# Mapkit crash when I add annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to add a simple annotation to my map. However it crash on the addAnnotation method. What is wrong? I am using Swift. The connection between map and the object in the Interface Builder is correctly set up. All I get is a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
class MyMapAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

And I try this in my view controller:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 46.830930, longitude: 7.705106)
let annotation = MyMapAnnotation(title: "Title", subtitle: "Subtitle", coordinate: coordinate)

if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coordinate) {
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MKAnnotation` protocol requires the properties to be `var` and the strings to be optional (`!`).

In the `MyMapAnnotation` class, change these declarations:

```
let title: String
let subtitle: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

to this:

```
var title: String!
var subtitle: String!
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

Comment: Just found out. Thank you:)